# Had Encrypted string using C#. Angular 4 not able to decrypt

Tags: c#, angular

I had encrypted string using C#, Same I want to decrypt using Angular 4. However Angular code is failing.

**C# Code**

```
 public string Encrypt<T>(string value)
                   where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("mykey", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("myIV"));

            SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();

            byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
            byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

            ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);

            using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        writer.Write(value);
                    }
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray());

                // "U2FsdGVkX1+r8rSCs7ReuU24235xwSG4kkcuKRU7nZU="
            }
        }
```

**Angular 4 Code -**

```
var ciphertext = "IV27YpfWyG0n3Rlfgm2LVL8D5FMqTj72awKR2LMYAhY=";

      var key = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse('mykey');
      var iv = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse('myIV');


        var decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            iv: iv,
            mode: crypto.mode.CBC,
            padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        console.log('Decrypted : ' + decrypted);
        console.log('Decrypted Value = ' + decrypted.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8));
```

Comment: Your Encoding doesn't match. Unicode vs UTF8

Comment: Are you accommodating the Base64 encoding on the Angular side?

Comment: My usual recommendation would be to write the complete round trip in both languages (from plain text, via encryption, back to plain text). Verify that both implementations are producing the same results at each stage. That way you're sure that both "agree" on the process. Once you can round-trip in both languages, it's then easy to pick a stage and swap from one language to the other.

Comment: Your key & iv are derived so are not equivalent to "mykey" or any other string when you come to decrypt. IV should not be reused so hard coding it in on the decrypt side is not a good idea.  If you want secure communication between a server & client use HTTPS, that's what its for.